# How to find broken queries in Access?

Tags: ms-access

How do I find broken queries in access.

i.e. Queries that might have broken because the underlying table was deleted or the name of the column in the table changed?

Is there an easy way -- rather than just opening each query running and checking if something has gone wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few notes that may be of interest, depending on your version of Access.

See: [GetDependencyInfo Method [Access 2003 VBA Language Reference]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa221244%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Do not forget that Track name AutoCorrect info is not a good thing, for the most part, but can be useful in certain circumstances.

```
Dim dinf As DependencyInfo

For j = 0 To CurrentData.AllQueries.Count - 1
    Set dinf = CurrentData.AllQueries(j).GetDependencyInfo

    For i = 0 To dinf.Dependencies.Count - 1
        ''Missing alias, query or table, as far as I can tell
        If dinf.Dependencies.Item(i).Name Like "MISSING:*" Then
            Debug.Print CurrentData.AllQueries(j).Name _
                & "   " & dinf.Dependencies.Item(i).Name
        End If
    Next
Next
```

You may need to update dependencies:

```
Application.CurrentProject.UpdateDependencyInfo
```

This will require a save.

Comment: I only turn on Name AutoCorrect when I specifically need to track dependencies for fixing things up. Once the job is done, I turn it off again. It works pretty well for that purpose. It should never be on in a production application, though.